# Can't send lat/lng's from Simplexml to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, simplexml

The values startlat,startlon,endlat,endlon show up in my query string as field names from the simplexml object.

I printed out the query string, look at the 3rd,4th,5th and 6th values

```
insert into *database.table* (mwayname, sectionname, startlat, startlon,   endlat,endlon,avgspd,avgocc,totvol,seclength,sectime)VALUES ('AKL-SH1-NB-RNM' , '1-NB  PAPAKURA OFF to PAPAKURA ON' , '->latitude', '->longitude' , '->latitude' , '->longitude' ,'98.7012505914656' , '3.0' , '12.0' , '0.309545' , '0.18817086803564703')
```

It's sending the simplexml-> into the query as text, yet other values, also numeric are not affected?? Surely not because the query contructor is within a loop ?

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

foreach($xml->return as $return)
{ 
echo '**********************',$return->name.'*****<br>';
echo '**********************',$return->reference.'*****<br>';

foreach($return->segments as $segments)
{
echo $return->name.'<br>';
echo $return->reference.'<br>';

echo $segments->carriagewaySegmentId.' ID <br>';
echo 'section name ',$segments->sectionName.'<br>';

echo 'start lat ',$segments->startLocation->latitude.'<br>';
echo 'start lng ',$segments->startLocation->longitude.' <br>';

echo 'end lat ',$segments->endLocation->latitude.'<br>';
echo 'end long ',$segments->endLocation->longitude.'<br>';

echo 'avg speed = ',$segments->averageSpeed. ' kmh avg<br>';
echo $segments->averageOccupancy. ' % of rd occupied<br>';
echo $segments->totalVolume. ' traffic volume<br>';
echo $segments->sectionLength. ' km<br>';
echo $segments->sectionTime. ' minutes<br>';
echo'<br>';
//send to mysql
$query = "insert into trafficstats.master (mwayname, sectionname, startlat, startlon,     endlat,endlon,avgspd,avgocc,totvol,seclength,sectime)VALUES ('$return->reference' ,   '$segments->sectionName' , '$segments->startLocation->latitude', '$segments->startLocation->longitude' ,  '$segments->endLocation->latitude' , '$segments->endLocation->longitude' ,'$segments- >averageSpeed' , '$segments-

>averageOccupancy' , '$segments->totalVolume' , '$segments->sectionLength' ,  '$segments->sectionTime')";
echo $query;
mysql_query($query);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: in the `$query`, try this: `'" . $segments->startLocation->latitude . "'`. I've had some issues with something similar in the past, breaking outside the string seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
$query = "insert into trafficstats.master (mwayname, sectionname, startlat, startlon,     endlat,endlon,avgspd,avgocc,totvol,seclength,sectime)
VALUES ('".$return->reference."' ,   '".$segments->sectionName."' , 
'".$segments->startLocation->latitude."', '".$segments->startLocation->longitude."' ,  
'".$segments->endLocation->latitude."' , '".$segments->endLocation->longitude."' ,
'".$segments- >averageSpeed."' , '".$segments->averageOccupancy."' , 
'".$segments->totalVolume."' , '".$segments->sectionLength."' ,  
'".$segments->sectionTime."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain the problem here, when PHP encounters a double-quoted string like `"something $foo->bar->baz something"`, it assumes you just want to replace `$foo->bar`, not the whole of `$foo->bar->baz`.

The solution is either (as others have pointed out) to concatenate the string together from multiple parts (`'something ' . $foo->bar->baz . ' something'`) or to surround the variable to replace in braces so that PHP knows it is all one variable (`"something {$foo->bar->baz} something"`).

See [the relevant section of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) for more on this syntax.

Comment: +1 for the explanation on what goes wrong instead of just giving the answer!